# Spawning multiple classes without tedious task of naming variables

Tags: c#, class

Is there a way to make multiple classes based on a number, say from a variable?
For example:

```
public class Person
{
    //stuff
}

new Person(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make multiple objects of the same class, at some point you're going to have to go through a loop (or a recursive method if you're feeling adventurous). Instead of creating a new variable for each object, you can store them all in a single array/list. For example:

```
public class Person {
}

//Inside some other class
int numClass = 5;
Person[] personList = new Person[numClass];
for(int i = 0; i <= numClass ; i++){
  personList[i] = new Person();
}
```

After that, `personList` will be an array of size 5 with each index containing a new `Person` object.

Comment: Many thanks! I was confused, but I see that loops are the way to go.

Comment: The correct type for `personList` is `Person[]`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes :) For instance, use a `List<Person>` and a *for loop*:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    people.Add(new Person());
}
```